# How to get the captured photo to main-thread?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, avcapturesession

I have a function to capture a photo with the camera via the `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection()` - method. 
The captured image is my return value for the `capture()` - method.

I want to save the captured photo to a variable in my ViewController an then perform a segue to another ViewController, which will show the photo. This does not seem to work, I get an `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` - Error.

I know that it is because of `var photo: UIImage!` being `nil`, but how can I get the photo-data into my main thread before calling the `performSegue...` function?

My photo function (inside my CameraSession-Class) and the session-queue:

```
var sessionQueue = dispatch_queue_create("CameraSession", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL) 

func capture(saveToGallery save: Bool) -> UIImage {
    var capturedImage = UIImage()

    let connection = self.output.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    connection.videoOrientation = .Portrait

    dispatch_async(sessionQueue, {
        self.output.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(
            connection, completionHandler: {
                (imageDataSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if imageDataSampleBuffer != nil {
                    let imageData: NSData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)
                         self.capturedImage = UIImage(data: imageData)

                    if save {
                        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.capturedImage!, nil, nil, nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    })

    return self.capturedImage!
}
```

My function in the ViewController-Class:

```
func capture() {
    let photo = cameraSession.capture(saveToGallery: true)
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showPhoto", sender: self) // This will switch to another ViewController, which shows the captured photo.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are capturing the photo asynchronously your function will reach

```
return self.capturedImage!
```

before the photo has been taken, and self.capturedImage is nil. You should move your logic that handles the segue somewhere after the image data has returned. This is probably easiest to accomplish by adding a callback as an argument to your capture method:

```
func capture(saveToGallery save: Bool, callback:UIImage -> Void) -> Void
```

and then instead of directly returning the UIImage, pass it as an argument to your callback:

```
let imageData: NSData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)
    self.capturedImage = UIImage(data: imageData)

if save {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.capturedImage!, nil, nil, nil)
}

callback(self.capturedImage)
```

Your UIViewController capture method would look something like:

```
func capture() {
    let photo = cameraSession.capture(saveToGallery: true, callback: {
    (photo: UIImage) -> Void in
    //save your photo locally in your UIViewController class here if you need to
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showPhoto", sender: self)
    })
}
```

Comment: The image is not taken in a ViewController-Class, so I can not add a segue to it. Is it possible to force my function to wait until `self.capturedImage` is not nil and then return it?

Comment: I'd recommend something like what Gargoyle describes, passing a block as a second argument to your capture method. Updated my answer to reflect this idea.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your capture(:_) method a block as a second parameter that takes a UIImage.  When you get the captured image created, after you save it, call that passed in block with the image.  Just dispatch it up to the main queue before you call it.   Then you'd have something more like:

```swift
func capture() {
    cameraSession.capture(saveToGallery: true) {
        [unowned self] image in
        self.myCapturedImage = image
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showPhoto", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part do you mean I should "dispatch it up to the main queue before you call it"?

Comment: After you save the image in your session queue. In there do a dispatch_async to the main queue and inside that dispatch block call the block passed into you

Comment: I still get the same error for the `photo` variable in my ViewController-Class. It still stays empty even if I do it with a callback/completion block and a dispatch_async for my `completion(image: self.capturedImage!)`

Comment: Then you're probably getting nil when you look at your capture data.

Answer (score 0):

You request the main (UI) thread like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //Do something in main thread
});
```